Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
I am having the following problem.
sh-5.2# bash bin/pinot-admin.sh AddTable -tableConfigFile /tmp/pinot/tb.json -schemaFile /tmp/pinot/sch.json -exec
[0.001s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:gc-pinot-controller.log instead.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/opt/pinot/lib/pinot-all-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2024/04/04 19:04:09.710 INFO [AddTableCommand] [main] Executing command: AddTable -tableConfigFile /tmp/pinot/tb.json -offlineTableConfigFile null -realtimeTableConfigFile null -schemaFile /tmp/pinot/sch.json -controllerProtocol http -controllerHost 172.18.0.4 -controllerPort 9000 -user null -password [hidden] -exec
2024/04/04 19:04:42.382 INFO [AddTableCommand] [main] {"code":500,"error":"org.apache.pinot.spi.stream.TransientConsumerException: org.apache.pinot.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata"}

I'm trying to connect Apache Pinot with Kafka via Docker
version: '3.7'
services:
 
  zookeeper:
      image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
      ports:
        - '2181:2181'
      environment:
        - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper


  pinot-controller:
    image: apachepinot/pinot:latest
    hostname: pinot-controller
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: StartController -zkAddress zookeeper:2181
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Dplugins.dir=/opt/pinot/plugins -Xms4G -Xmx8G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Xlog:gc:gc-pinot-controller.log"
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  pinot-broker:
    image: apachepinot/pinot:latest
    hostname: pinot-broker
    ports:
      - "8099:8099"
    command: StartBroker -zkAddress zookeeper:2181
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Dplugins.dir=/opt/pinot/plugins -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Xlog:gc:gc-pinot-broker.log"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - pinot-controller

  pinot-server:
    image: apachepinot/pinot:latest
    hostname: pinot-server
    ports:
      - "8098:8098"
    command: StartServer -zkAddress zookeeper:2181
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Dplugins.dir=/opt/pinot/plugins -Xms4G -Xmx16G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Xlog:gc:gc-pinot-server.log"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - pinot-controller

Does anyone have any idea of ​​the possible error?

You need KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092

Also, Zookeeper isn't used anymore for that kafka container. Are you sure it's working?
